# `ondragstart` changeable CSS styles

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, dom-events

What are the changeable CSS styles valid for `ondragstart` function call?

HTML

```
<li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="id"> Item </li>
```

CSS

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.target.style.background = '#f1f1f1';
    ev.target.style.boxShadow = '2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.39)';
    ev.target.style.transform = 'rotate(-3deg) skew(5deg)';

    ev.dataTransfer.setData("idOfItem", ev.target.id);
}
```

In above `background` and `box-shadow` are applying for the `li` item where `transform` is not working

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vnwx95mL/ (Thanks @Rayon)

**NOTE: original element is transforming. But there is another one which is coming with the mouse. That have the issue.**

[image: sample-changed-values]

Comment: Where have you applied "transform" ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ct7po6q7/

Comment: `transform` should be working for this. In a quick CodePen demo I just setup it seemed to work fine. The problem I had with your code above was the extra `)` between the ending quote for the transform and the `;` ending the line.

Comment: @bkbooth The original element is transforming. The issue is with the dragged element which is coming with the mouse as in the picture.  Fiddle given by Rayon have the same issue. Have removed the extra )

Comment: It seems like an issue with Chrome. On firefox, it works fine.

Comment: Seems to be an issue in Chrome only, you can write a bug report to Chrome and wait for them to fix it, or you *could* use [JqueryUI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a browser-specific issue and has nothing to do with the Javascript functionality used. Even if you apply the following class *beforehand* on your element and try to drag it, the draggable element is still without the applied styling.

```
.myClass {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg) skew(5deg);
  transform:rotate(-3deg) skew(5deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gnxccyz7/

However, here is the solution to your problem: just create a child element inside your draggable element and apply the style on that. This is also working on Chrome!

Javascript:

```
function drag(ev) {
  ev.target.className = 'myClass';
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("idOfItem", ev.target.id);
}
```

CSS:

```
.myClass span {
  display:block;
  background:#f1f1f1;
  -webkit-box-shadow:box-shadow:2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.39);
  box-shadow:2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.39);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg) skew(5deg);
  transform:rotate(-3deg) skew(5deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sbh4j9ag/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know browser does following during `dragstart`:

1. creates drag feedback image, simply - makes screenshot of element
2. shows this image during d'n'd

It is intresting that some styles on drag target element, such as `transform` are ignored during drag feedback image creation (@scooterlord pointed already)

---

There are many libraries which resolve such issues, e.g. http://interactjs.io/

Native d'n'd API is still not standartized and have missing must-have features, so i advice you to use any library for that